# MongoDB - Conditionally check value for null in the pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, bson

In my MongoDB doc, I have `updated` field of type string

In the pipeline, I'm consuming that field
...

```
{
   ...
   "$dayOfMonth", new BsonDocument(){
      {"$dateFromString", new BsonDocument(){{"dateString", "$updated"}}
    }
    ...
}
```

Everything seems to be in order if I have values in the collection document but if pipeline steps into the document with no value I'm getting

> Command aggregate failed: $dateFromString requires that 'dateString'
> be a string, found: date with value 2022-02-23T01:54:21.467Z.

How can I conditionally check in the pipeline for the value of this property?

Comment: The error seems is with `$dateFromString` found the `updated` was a `Date` but not `string`. Just curious why you state the error that the field is with no value / `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$toDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) instead of `$dateFromString`.

```
{
  $dayOfMonth: {
    $toDate: "$updated"
  }
}
```

> BsonDocument

```cs
{
   "$dayOfMonth", new BsonDocument() {
      { "$toDate", "$updated" }
   }
}
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vEYmNvCYD6q)